# Брать и давать интервью

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как лучше выражаться в устной речи: человек дал мне интервью, или я взял у человека интервью? Или варианты равноценны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что  **не всегда равноценны**, как не равноценны глаголы *брать* и *взять*.

ИНТЕРВЬЮ.  Предназначенная для печати, радио или телевидения беседа журналиста с каким-л. лицом (политиком, деятелем искусства, учёным и т.п.).

Выбор глагола может зависеть от того, насколько это лицо заинтересовано в беседе и готово к ней. Можно в этом плане **сравнить варианты**:

(1) *Наш корреспондент сразу после победного матча с трудом пробился к кромке поля и **взял** интервью у прославленного капитана.*

(2) Он разрешил нам снять коллекцию и **сам дал** интервью нашему журналисту. Всего за несколько дней до отъезда Троцкий **дал** интервью New York Times.

Comment: Я исходил из того, что если говорят, что "кто-то взял интервью", значит, интервьюируемый согласился его дать. По-моему, они **чаще всего** взаимозаменяемы: то есть, если кто-то *даёт,* это не обязательно значит, что это его инициатива, равно как и если кто-то *берёт* интервью, это не значит, что другой только из вежливости соглашается.

Comment: Артем, но я всего лишь говорю, что НЕ ВСЕГДА равноценны и привожу примеры, когда подходит именно тот глагол, который был использован. Вряд ли хорошо звучит такая фраза: Наш корреспондент с трудом пробился к кромке поля,  где прославленный капитан дал ему интервью.

Comment: Да с этим я согласен! Смысл обычно один, но вариант лучше выбирать в соответствии с контекстом.

Comment: Я тоже не представляю, как можно дать интервью тому, кто его не берёт, или взять его у не давшего интервью. Даже в сложных случаях порывающийся "дать" интервью добивается, чтобы его "взяли", а желающий "взять" интервью уговаривает, чтобы его "дали". Не имеет значения, кто из упомянутых участников приложил больше усилий к согласию относительно состоявшегося интервью. 
_Наш корреспондент с трудом пробился к кромке поля, и прославленный капитан охотно дал ему интервью._

Comment: Это вряд ли. Может, он вполне охотно дал бы интервью десятку таких журналистов, да обстановка к тому не располагала. Здесь инициатива исходила от  того, кто хочет взять, а не дать, ну хотя бы несколько слов услышать. Поэтому  прославленный капитан мог только охотно пообещать дать интервью чуть позже, примерно через пару деньков, когда время будет.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, они равнозначны и взаимозаменяемы. Это два способа выразить одну мысль. Вариант надо выбирать в зависимости от контекста: в одном лучше одно действующее лицо, в другом другое.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты в первом приближении равнозначны, но не равноценны. Выбор зависит от контекста. В первую голову от того, какое положение в обществе занимает интервьюируемый. Президент интервью дает, у случайного прохожего интервью берут. Разговор корреспондента с бомжом вряд ли назовут "интервью".
Есть и другие стилистические особенности.

Comment: Что значит "равнозначны, но не равноценны"?

Comment: Я же написал. Значение одинаково, акценты и стилистика могут быть разные.

Comment: Ну да, я понял, тоже примерно так же считаю, просто слово "равноценны" непонятно, как трактовать.